# Setting DNS settings on Network Adapter - Error Code 84

Tags: dns, powershell-2.0, get-wmiobject

I using PowerShell with the WMI class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration to apply static DNS settings on my wireless network adapter. However, the method failed with the error code 84. Below is the coding:

```
$dnsSettings = "8.8.8.8"
$wmi = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where { $_.Description -like "*wireless*" }
$wmi.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($dnsSettings)
```

Anyone can kindly advice?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `-Filter` expects a WMI filter expression, not a PowerShell filter expression.

Change

```
"Description -like wireless"
```

to

```
"Description like '%wireless%'"
```

Comment: Thanks, I also encountered issue with the -Filter expression earlier and now using the "Where-Object" cmdlet instead. However, I still getting the error code 84 when applying the DNS settings.

Comment: @PDGamer Try defining `$dnsSettings` as an array (`$dnsSettings = @("8.8.8.8")`).

Comment: Hi, I had tried to define $dnsSettings as an array but still encounter the same error. I observed that the network is required to be connected for this to work. Would like to ask if there's a workaround this? Reason is that there might not be a network available during script execution.